# Moodle answer format as per custom plugin config?

Tags: php, content-management-system, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

Steps we have completed.
1. Created custom plugin for entering question type
2. Entered question as per our need

Steps we need to complete
1. Display question's answers format, just when we choose our plugin, not for all global options(Multi select, true-false, compare etc.)

Problem we are facing
1. How to get the current questions answer's from database?

If we want to create an REST API for these details, what should be the appropriate procedure? Any reference links will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the webservice as a local plugin.

In the current plugin, you can write SQL query or you can use question API to fetch the questions and answers.